# How to apply role-based security on struts2

Tags: struts2, spring-security

Hi I am going to apply role-based security on my struts2 application but could not find any working tutorial, most of them defined the username and passwords in the xml file but I am looking for the one with database access.

what I want to do :

Have a login page when user is logged in access database to authorize and then provide access to different resources of the application based on his role.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949808/securing-struts-application-in-action-level

Comment: @Rohit, your example does not use database as well and its very vague.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, it might be helpful to supply some info regarding how you want to use it, whether something like Spring Security is an option, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

There are two levels of this security
 1. Server side
 2. Client side

Initially you have to setup a table in your db say task_permissions which states role based tasks permissions.

then this method will help you on server side

```
private boolean isTaskOpAllowed(String taskId, String operation) throws SQLException {

    String taskAllowedSql = "select"+operation+"from task_permissions where  role_id = ? and task_id = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    boolean allowed = false;
    Connection conn = <make db connection>
    String role = <take role of user from session>
    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(taskAllowedSql);
        pstmt.setString(1, roleId);
        pstmt.setString(2, taskId);
        rst = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (rst.next()) {
            allowed = rst.getString(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        throw se;
    } finally {
                   cleanUpDbConnection(pstmt, rst);
    }
    return allowed;
}
```

And on jsp you can add this check on different modules so before rendering then above function will be called and tell you whether to show this info to this role user or not

```
<s:if test="%{@<packagename>.TaskSecurityHandler@isTaskOpAllowed(task,operation)}">
```

**EDIT:**
The other way round is to cache the results of task based permissions and every time query to that cache it will save db hit.

Make a `RoleTaskPrmsBean.java` with properties 
`String role;

String task;

String operation1;

String operation2;`
and so on.
now on system or server startup fetch all records from db task_permissions table and make that much objects of this class put them in a Map against `key:task+role`. Now every time when above function runs you can query to that Map rather then db.

Comment: This <s:if> is in jsp not in html. and jsp translates to servlet so dont worry no security layer is in hands of client to tweak with

Comment: @Rizstien  Thanks, should I define the task parameter as a constant on jsp? where did you use the operation parameter?

Comment: Yes your task and operations will be constants. Task for example USERS MODULE and Operation such as Update.

Comment: Yes I got that but I cant find out where you used operation parameter in the method.

Comment: I have my code updated. By operation i meant update, insert, delete etc. so in db table you can have columns for these operations update,insert,delete and their values can be 'true' or 'false' so this method will return you either this role user allowed for specified operation or not.

Comment: is there any other method to check it without comparing with the database table because reading from database is costly.

Comment: Yes, at server startup build up your cache for for role based prmission and everytime query to that cache map not to db

Comment: what do you mean by cache ? would you clarify ?